# Server loses connection after three days

Tags: networking, network-manager

I'm having some trouble with an Ubuntu 20.04 server which loses connection after three days.
The server boots using Dracut. What it does, after booting up and getting an IP address from the DHCP server, is stopping NetworkManager. I did this because some people pointed out that NetworkManager could be causing this.

I would like that the server stayed with the IP address that it got after booting.

```bsh
root@host:/var/log# systemctl list-units --all '*etwork*'
  UNIT                               LOAD   ACTIVE   SUB     DESCRIPTION                           
  networkd-dispatcher.service        loaded active   running Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd
  NetworkManager-wait-online.service loaded inactive dead    Network Manager Wait Online           
  NetworkManager.service             loaded inactive dead    Network Manager                       
  systemd-networkd.service           loaded inactive dead    Network Service                       
  network-online.target              loaded active   active  Network is Online                     
  network-pre.target                 loaded inactive dead    Network (Pre)                         
  network.target                     loaded active   active  Network                               

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

7 loaded units listed.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

In the logs it can be seen that the machine suddenly cannot contact with influxdb in a different machine and after that I cannot ssh neither.
Journalctl logs:

```bsh
Aug 14 11:19:01 myhost pulseaudio[67379]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
...
Aug 14 11:58:05 myhost telegraf[3018]: 2020-08-14T09:58:05Z E! [outputs.influxdb] When writing to [http://someip]: Post http://someip/write?consistency=any&db=telegraf: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awai>
Aug 14 11:58:05 myhost telegraf[3018]: 2020-08-14T09:58:05Z E! [agent] Error writing to outputs.influxdb: could not write any address
```

The only other related thing that I can see in the logs is this:

```bsh
Aug 14 10:34:08 myhost systemd-timesyncd[2889]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
```

But that is a recurrent thing and I'm not sure if it is related to this problem or just some component of the network blocking the connection to that IP address.

Comment: Do you think maybe that the DHCP server have a lease time of 3 days? DHCP leases do not last forever, you know... For a server it would make sense to either set a static IP address, or let the DHCP give it a fixed IP address every time.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Thank you for your reply. I think it might be that. I checked the running processes and there is no `dhclient` so I guess that when the lease is over it is not renewed.  Is there a way to enable dhclient so it can renew the ip?

Comment: You say in the OP that after getting a DCHP address, you stop NetworkManager - why? I'd imagine that NetworkManager running would among other things ensure that you get a renewed DHCP lease. But I'm not really an expert on the Ubuntu network rendering tools.

Comment: I stop NetworkManager because I always had this problem with this machine. A colleague pointed out that disabling NetworkManager could solve the problem.

Comment: Your colleague is wrong. Fixing NetworkManager is right.

Comment: `journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager` to see the logs, as NetworkManager gets the IP address via DHCP, is killed by you, and thereafter does nothing. Changing the system without understanding the change and its consequences first is the Bad Way.